# Does someone know a transparent captive portal for active directory?

Tags: logs, active-directory, samba, captive-portal

I'm using samba4 for windows hosts...
I need to enable a captive portal for logging INTERNET traffic transparently : I mean logging-in to the active directory via windows would also cause to log-in in the captive portal. So users are prompted for their password only one time...

Does someone know a program *(can be Microsoft based)* for that?